# Converting Objective C with Pointers to Kotlin

Tags: c, swift, sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project. Need to integrate SQLCipher, which we have done for the Android part, and now I am working on the iOS side.

I have built SQLCipher and integrated using c_interop.

SQLCipher documentation for Swift says this:

```
var rc: Int32
var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
var stmt: OpaquePointer? = nil
let password: String = "correct horse battery staple"
rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db)
rc = sqlite3_key(db, password, Int32(password.utf8CString.count))
```

I was looking at this as it is easier to convert Swift to Kotlin, however since it is using the c_interop for KMM, I guess it uses the normal C code, which SQLCipher defines as this:

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
bool sqlcipher_valid = NO;

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
const char* key = [@"BIGSecret" UTF8String];
sqlite3_key(db, key, (int)strlen(key));
```

I have done this part in Kotlin like this:

```
var rc: Int
val db: CValuesRef<CPointerVar<cnames.structs.sqlite3>>? = null
val db2: CValuesRef<cnames.structs.sqlite3>? = null

if(sqlite3_open(databasePath, db) == SQLITE_OK) {
   NSLog("Successfully opened connection to database")
}
rc = sqlite3_key(db2, null, 0)
```

However I keep getting crashes in XCode at **sqlite3_open(databasePath, db)**

It says **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)**

I'm assuming the issues are because of Pointers which I have no familiarity with really, and not sure how to convert to Kotlin.

From SQLCiphers example, they pass a string to sqlite3_key, however when I try pass a string it says **Type mismatch: inferred type is String but CValuesRef<*>?**

The first db I declare for sqlite3_open is a different type than the one for sqlite3_key, however their example shows them using the same db, so really not sure how exactly to proceed with this.

Full SQLCipher implementation is [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/)

Comment: You seem to be dealing with swift and kotlin... pardon me but I see no C code ?

Comment: @user426 apologies, I was looking at the Swift implementation as it is easier to convert to Kotlin, however since it is using the c_interop I believe it is actually the C implementation. I updated the OP. Thanks!

Comment: This code is `Objective C` not `C`. An this code is bad here is a prove: `const char* key = [@"BIGSecret" UTF8String];`, should be just: `const char* key  = "BIGSecret";`.

Comment: @MarekR I see, an iOS dev had a quick look with me and said it was more C because of the pointers etc so I just thought it was C, I'm unfamiliar with C and Objective C since I am mainly an Android developer.
Any ideas on how I could convert this over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out and hope this helps.
First I had to do everything inside ***memscoped*** so we had access to ***alloc()*** methods.

Then I realised one issue was my database path was incorrect.
Using XCode you can click on Window -> Devices & Simulators, click your app, then click the cog and press Download Container. Then inspect the container of your app to see where the database is. For me it was inside **Application Support**.

You can then check if your DB exists like so:

```
val fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
val doesDBExist = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath)
```

Then define a pointer like this:

```
val db: CPointerVar<sqlite3> = allocPointerTo()
```

**sqlite3_open** actually creates a new db if it doesn't find one, so I used the **v2** method to just check if it exists. Notice that we use **.ptr** to reference the pointer as it is passed in.

```
val openResult = sqlite3_open_v2(databasePath, db.ptr, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, null)
```

Then if you want to check your key you can do this (Replace null with your key):

```
val keyResult = sqlite3_key(db.value, null, 0)
```

This should give you a result of 1, which is an error. As noted on the SQLCipher documentation, you need to perform a further step.

```
val result = sqlite3_exec(db.value, "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", null, null, null)
```

This will try and perform a command on your DB, if your database is not encrypted, then should return fine using null. If you pass in a passphrase it should be able to query the DB.

We then need to close the db

```
sqlite3_close(db.value)
```

So the full method for me, when I wanted to check if my DB was encrypted or not, was like this:

```
override fun isDatabaseEncrypted(databasePath: String): Boolean {
    memScoped {
        val fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        val doesDBExist = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath)
        NSLog("Result is $doesDBExist")

        val db: CPointerVar<sqlite3> = allocPointerTo()

        val openResult = sqlite3_open_v2(databasePath, db.ptr, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, null)
        NSLog("openResult is $openResult")
        val keyResult = sqlite3_key(db.value, null, 0)
        NSLog("keyResult is $keyResult")
        val result = sqlite3_exec(db.value, "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", null, null, null)
        sqlite3_close(db.value)

        NSLog("Result is $result")
        return result != SQLITE_OK
    }
}
```

I know this is going into more detail than my original question, but hopefully it explains things a bit better for anybody who has similar questions to me.